# Anchor links for accordion menu on different page not working (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a similar problem to one I posted before. I have a page built in Bootstrap, and I have several links that jump the reader to anchor links that require an accordion menu to open a specific tab. With the help of Stack Overflow I got it to work, but it only works on my computer and not online (my unfinished draft is on verbiadastra.com - I mean the links under "Services").
My other problem is that I can't get it to open a tab that's on a different page rather than the same one (from index.html to contact.html)
Here's the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trj87ytj/34/).
I would really appreciate your help!

Here's the HTML:

```
<p>Go to <a href="#tab1" onclick="openTab1()">Tab1</a>.</p>
<p>Go to <a href="#tab2" onclick="openTab2()">Tab2</a>.</p>
<p>Go to <a href="#tab3" onclick="openTab3()">Tab3</a>.</p>

<section id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 wow fadeInDown">
               <div class="tab-wrap"> 
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="parrent pull-left">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="analistic-01"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>Tab1</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="tehnical"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Tab2</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" class="tehnical"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>Tab3</a></li>                                   
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="parrent media-body">
                            <div class="tab-content">

                                <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab1">
                                    <div class="media">
                                       <div class="pull-left">
                                           <img class="img-responsive" src="images/services/tab1-1.png">
                                           <br>
                                           <img class="img-responsive" src="images/services/tab1-2.png">
                                           <br>
                                           <img class="img-responsive" src="images/services/tab1-3.png">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <a name="Tab1"></a>
                                            <h2>Tab1</h2>
                                            <p>Tab1Tab1Tab1.</p>                         
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
                                    <div class="media">
                                       <div class="pull-left">
                                           <img class="img-responsive" src="images/services/tab2.jpg">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <a name="Tab2"></a>
                                           <h2>Tab2</h2>                                                <p>Tab2Tab2Tab2.</p>                                                                                             </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>

                                 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
                                     <div class="media">
                                         <div class="pull-left">
                                             <img class="img-responsive" src="images/services/tab3.jpg">
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="media-body">
                                             <a name="Tab3"></a>
                                             <h2>Tab3</h2>
                                             <p>Tab3Tab3Tab3 </p>

                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                                                                 </div> <!--/.tab-content-->  
                        </div> <!--/.media-body--> 
                    </div> <!--/.media-->     
                </div><!--/.tab-wrap-->               
            </div><!--/.col-sm-6-->
                                                    </div><!--/.row-->
    </div><!--/.container-->
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
var openTab1 = function() {
$('[href="#tab1"]').tab('show');
}

var openTab2 = function() {
$('[href="#tab2"]').tab('show');
}

var openTab3 = function() {
$('[href="#tab3"]').tab('show');
}
```

Comment: I can navigate between tabs..

Comment: That's not what I meant. I mean the links under "Services" in the navigation menu bar that are supposed to take the reader down to the accordion menu and open the tab for the service selected.

Comment: Now that's suddenly working too (when you're already on index.html). I had to click on it more than once though, and after that, it worked. Now my problem is that it doesn't work if you're on contact.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out - here's my solution in case it helps anyone, and maybe someone can let me know if I should have done it differently:

I deleted the JavaScript code I posted above, and my links no longer call that function on click. Instead, I write a function that is called on page load: It checks if there is any hashtag (#) in the URL, and if there is, I have it compare its value to the ones I'm using to call the different tabs. Then for each tab id, I have it do the function that opens the tab. Then it also jumps down to a div that has the id of the hashtag (instead of the link anchors, which I learned are obsolete in HTML5). Here's the function:

```
<body class="homepage" onload="TabHash()">
```

and then:

```
<script> 
var TabHash = function() {          
//check if hash tag exists in the URL
if(window.location.hash) { 
    //set the value as a variable, and remove the #
    var hash_value = window.location.hash.replace('#', ''); 
    if (hash_value == "Tab1Name") {
    $('[href="#tab1"]').tab('show');
    }
    if (hash_value == "Tab2Name") {
    $('[href="#tab2"]').tab('show');
    }
    if (hash_value == "Tab3Name") {
    $('[href="#tab3"]').tab('show');
    }        
 }
}
</script>
```

The links look like this:

```
<a href="index.html#Tab1Name">Go to Tab 1.</a>
<a href="index.html#Tab2Name">Go to Tab 2.</a>
<a href="index.html#Tab3Name">Go to Tab 3.</a>
```